# Is it possible to use index in wpf control's name (e.g. TextBox(i)) to lessen code duplication?

Tags: c#, wpf

My application interface is shown below: (ignore the control names first)

[image]

When `Button1` is clicked, `OutputBox1` will display the string in `InputBox`, same to `Button2`, when `Button2` is clicked, `OutputBox2` will display the string in `InputBox`.

My question is it possible to do something like this: When `Button(i)` is clicked, `OutputBox(i).Text = InputBox.Text`, so that there is less code duplication..?

By the way, this is just a simple illustration. My real problem is not as simple as this (involve data binding to listview). I just want to know whether it is possible or not.

Thanks for any suggestion and ideas.

Comment: write your Button click on the base control just like this <Grid Button.Click="YourEvent"> this will catch all button click event.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can create your own list of controls in code behind and use indexer of it.

   ```
   public partial class SomeView : UserControl
   {
   private List<Button> ButtonCollection;
   private List<TextBox> TargetCollection;


   public SomeView()
   {
       InitializeComponent();

       ButtonCollection = new List<Button>
       {
           Button1,
           Button2,
           Button3
       };

       TargetCollection = new List<TextBox>
       {
           OutputTextBox1,
           OutputTextBox2,
           OutputTextBox3
       };
   }

   private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       var index = ButtonCollection.IndexOf(sender as Button);

       if (index >= 0)
       {
           var target = TargetCollection[index];

           ...
       }
   }
   }
   ```
2. In xaml, if your use mvvm and commands, you can pass outbox elements in command parameter.

   ```
   <TextBox Name="OutputTextBox1" />
   <Button Name="Button1"
           Command="{Binding ShowText}"
           CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=OutputTextBox1}" />
   <TextBox Name="OutputTextBox2" />
   <Button Name="Button2"
           Command="{Binding ShowText}"
           CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=OutputTextBox3}" />
   <TextBox Name="OutputTextBox3" />
   <Button Name="Button3"
           Command="{Binding ShowText}"
           CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=OutputTextBox2}" />
   ```

Then in command handler:

```
    private void ShowText(object obj)
    {
        var textBox = obj as TextBox;

    }
```

3. If not, you can store target elements in Tag property:

   ```
   <TextBox Name="OutputTextBox1" />
   <Button Name="Button1"
           Tag="{Binding ElementName=OutputTextBox1}"
           Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" />
   <TextBox Name="OutputTextBox2" />
   <Button Name="Button2"
           Tag="{Binding ElementName=OutputTextBox2}"
           Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"/>
   <TextBox Name="OutputTextBox3" />
   <Button Name="Button3"
           Tag="{Binding ElementName=OutputTextBox3}"
           Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"/>
   ```

And handler like this:

```
    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var target = (sender as Button)?.Tag as TextBox;

        if (target != null)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also to it completely in xaml, with an EventTrigger from the Interaction Library and a ChangePropertyAction, Code for the first Button (Button1 connectet to OutputBox1)

```
<Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Button1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Margin="20">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Text" TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=OutPutBox1}" Value="{Binding ElementName=InputBox, Path=Text}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

In order to work, you need to reference following librarys:
System.Windows.Interactivity for the Interaction namespace (Interaction.Triggers and Eventtrigger)
Microsoft.Expression.Interactions for the ChangePropertyAction